# HTML5 Video - Removing Maximize button

Tags: css, html, video

Currently when viewing a video in iPad and using the controls i'm seeing the maximize button.. however I don't want this to be displayed.  Is there an easy way to toggle this maximize button off?

video code:

```
<video width="309" controls="true" poster="bla.jpg">
     <source = "video.ogv">
     <source = "video.m4v">
<video>
```

I've removed the controls but that simply removes all the controls, where as I'm looking only to remove the maximize button which presents itself.

Thank you

Comment: That should be `controls` or `control="controls"`. `true` is not a valid value for the attribute: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/common-microsyntaxes.html#boolean-attribute

Comment: David- Thanks, i've fixed that.

Comment: You could try http://videojs.com/

Comment: trying not to use any 3rd party libraries as it needs to be very light and fast for the iPad.  Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Native controls are an all or nothing prospect.